# Understanding the blow up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ in $\left<x_0,x_1\right>$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

The following is an example from Gathmann's notes on algebraic geometry:

[image]

I am having problems with showing, rigorously, that $\tilde X$ is given by the prescribed equations. First, I do not get why the RHS is even a closed subset. Yes, it is given by the zero set of a polynomial equation- but the topology on $\mathbb{A}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$ is given by the product topology, and I do not see how to show that a zero set of a polynomial equation is closed in this product topology. Second, why can't we have a smaller closed subset containing $\Gamma$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The topology on a product of varieties is not the topological product topology. We want $\Bbb A_k^1\times \Bbb A^1_k$ to be homeomorphic to $\Bbb A^2_k$, after all, and for that the product topology just won't do (the diagonal $\{(x, x)\mid x\in k\}$ wouldn't be closed, for instance). Presumably your book talks about this the first time it mentions products.

Comment: That's a great comment, thank you! I didn't think about it. It does talk about it when it talk about product of affine variety - I checked now. But I don't find something about general varieties. I'll look it up on the internet, anyway.

Comment: Topology is a local thing, and projective varieties are locally affine, so in some sense it's enough to discuss the topology on affine varieties. In this specific example, you can cover $\Bbb P^1$ with two affine subvarieties $V_1$ and $V_2$, and then you can look at $\Bbb A^2\times V_1$ and $\Bbb A_2\times V_2$ separately to get their topologies, then take their union to get all of $\Bbb A^2\times \Bbb P^1$.

Comment: First of all thank you - your comments are very useful. I think I came up with a solution. Denote the affine patches of $\mathbb{A}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$ by $U_1$,$U_2$. Then $\tilde{X}$ is given on each patch by poly equations (on $y_0\neq 0$ for example it is $x_0y_1=x_1$) hence is closed in each patch, and hence is closed in $\tilde X$. It suffices therefore to check that $\bar{\Gamma}$ contains $\tilde{X}$, which is true as $\tilde{X}$ is the union of the closures on each patch, and the closure contains the union of closures on each patch by simple topology. Is it true? (...)

Comment: (...) Also, it seem so complicated- is there a more simple way to see it?